# How to display online images in j2me?

Tags: java, image, java-me

I know how to display local images in J2me. How can I display an online image? The following code (the image URL below is just for demo purposes) does not yield anything.

`Image logo = Image.createImage("http://whatever.com/img/whatever.png");`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the image manually via a `HttpConnection`

Use this method to load the image:

```
public Image loadImage(String url) throws IOException {
    HttpConnection hpc = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    try {
      hpc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
      int length = (int) hpc.getLength();
      byte[] data = new byte[length];
      dis = new DataInputStream(hpc.openInputStream());
      dis.readFully(data);
      return Image.createImage(data, 0, data.length);
    } finally {
      if (hpc != null)
        hpc.close();
      if (dis != null)
        dis.close();
    }
}
```

See also [this tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0430__J2ME/LoadImagewithHttpConnection.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This was VERY useful.

You used LCDUI. For those (like me) who want to use LWUIT, here is another example http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/bitworks/JSONFACEBOOK/src/hello/AuxMet.java

Answer (score 1):

Your first port of call for questions like this should be the [MIDP 2.0 Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html).

There you will see that `createImage` has an [overload](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#createImage%28java.io.InputStream%29) which accepts an `InputStream`; this will do what you need.

Alternatively, you can download the entire image into a byte array and use [yet another alternative form](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#createImage%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) of `createImage`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Checking out the Javadocs is always a good start.